# Exchangeable or iid random variables and linear conditioning

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,\ldots ,X_N$ be independent identically distributed random variables (or, more generally, exchangeable random variables,
but let's assume independence for simplicity). Then 
$$
E(X_i\mid X_1+\ldots +X_N)=\frac{1}{N}(X_1+\ldots +X_N)
$$
by exchangeability. Indeed, we know that the left-hand side above is the same for any $i=1,\ldots ,N$, and 
the sum of these is just $X_1+\ldots +X_N$. It is very interesting that the property does not depend on the distribution of the $X_i$'s.

Now, consider more general linear conditioning, of the form $E(X_i\mid F(X_1,\ldots ,X_N))$ (where $F$ is linear), 
or even $E(X_i\mid A\vec X)$, where $A$ is a matrix (i.e., we impose several conditions). In simplest cases this would lead to expressions 
like $E(X\mid X+2Y)$ or $E(X\mid X+Y,X+Z)$, where $X,Y,Z$ are iid. Experiments immediately show that these types of expectations depend on the 
distribution of $X$. My questions are:

> Have such conditional expectations been studied before? What can be said about them? Are there any good references?

EDIT: Let's assume for simplicity that the random variables are continuous.

Comment: Of course this should depend on the distribution.  Say the r.v.s are distributed over some subset of the rationals, and we consider the linear expression $\pi X_1 + \pi^2 X_2 + \cdots + \pi^n X_n$.  Then the entire sequence of r.v.s is determined by the value of this sum.  Whereas if the variables take the values $\{1, \pi, \pi^2, \ldots \}$ then (much) less can be deduced from this sum.  But yea, that's pretty weird at first glance.  I don't know any references, but that doesn't say much.

Comment: (Even simple looking expressions like $X_1 + 2 X_2 + \cdots + 2^n X_n$ can completely determine the $X_i$ if the variables take values in $\{0, 1\}$)  I think it might be interesting to consider the entropy perhaps?  [Not that this comment says anything.]

Comment: @PatDevlin thank you! these are interesting examples, I think I saw some problems like this recently on the arxiv. Let's say RV's are continuous, I'll make an edit

Comment: Take the random variables uniformly distrusted on $[1,2)$ so continuous.  Then again  $X_1 + 2 X_2 + \cdots + 2^n X_n$ will determine the values

Comment: @Henry how about just $E(X\mid X+Y, X+Z)$ ?